# React Hook, how to set an array into a list of objects controllably

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to set an array into a list of objects within a useState. How to do so?

```
const [ingredients, setIngredients] = useState([])

const [recipe, setReceipe] = useState({title : "", description: "", receipeIsPrivate : isPrivate, ingredients: '', directions : ''})

setReceipe(...recipe, [ingredients] : ingredients)
```

when i log the recipe list, i receive an array with empty string. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setReceipe is a constant function you need to call, you are currently trying to reassign it with the = operator (which is impossible, since it is a constant)

i.e.

```
setReceipe(... recipe, [ingredients]: ingredients)
```

Comment: Sorry that was a misstypo onto this forum on my part. i tried setReceipe(...receipe, [ingredients] : ingredients), and setReceipe({...receipe, ingredients : ingredients}). Both i tried did not work. In the first one i get a parsing error, the type cast expression is expected to be wrapped with parenthesis. And the second example i gave, with no error, i logged it and it displayed ingredients:[""]

Comment: Ah ok, in that case the other thing i'm noticing is you're spreading the recipe directly into the setRecipe call, instead of spreading it into an object, i.e. setRecipe({...recipe, ingredients}) - that might be your problem